# Laravel blade. Best way to show an image size according to the size of the screen

Tags: image, laravel, width

For each record, I have two images, small and large size. What is the best way to show an image size according to the size of the screen?

I know I can use css and mediaquery and show the small or large image using a div display none / block, but in this way, I understand that the user **has downloaded both images even if they are not displayed**, is that correct? Then, the page load increases. If so, what is the best option to do this?

Comment: https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-images/

Comment: @ThomasMoors - Never knew this. This is pure gold. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMoors This is great! I'm going to see if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem the most efficient way is using the `User-Agent` to detect if a client is desktop, tablet or mobile.

I prefer to use [Mobile_Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) or [jenssegers/agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent) (based on `Mobile_Detect`).

**Edit**

Recently I installed the [Google Pagespeed Module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/) on my server. There is a filter, [`resize_rendered_image_dimensions`](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/reference-image-optimize#resize_rendered_image_dimensions), that returns images with sizes of the current client view (exactly what you are looking for).

Some other implementation would be lazyloading with Javascript and adding dimensions to the requested url depending on the viewport sizes.

Comment: I would like to concur: User-Agents change all the time and this makes it hard to maintain this solution. It can be done purely on screen size, which will keep working.

Comment: I had seen the User-Agents but they do not convince me for the reason indicated by Thomas. I've thought about doing something by getting the screen size with jQuery and then doing a conditional in php to show me one or another image; but I do not know how to pass the screen size to the php conditional. I think this would be a good way. I have also seen solutions with cookies but have the problem that at the first view, we would not know the screen size or if the user has cookies disabled ...